# Fedora 17 x86_64 Nvidia R310 Driver

Tags: fedora, nvidia-graphics-card

EDIT: I updated the question to be more clear.

I am currently running Nvidia's proprietary driver (kmod-nvidia-3.6.7-4.fc17.x86_64-304.64-1.fc17.x86_64) on Fedora 17 x86_64. Apparently, there is a [huge performance improvement](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=nvidia_r310_linux&num=1) with Nvidia's new "R310" driver, so I'd like to try it out myself.

My question is: Is there some way to install this driver without totally destroying my current setup? A kmod or akmod would probably be ideal (a kernel update causes boot problems without an akmod), but it doesn't seem to be available in RPMFusion; I can only find it at Nvidia's website, which is apparently a bad way to do things.

Also, Ubuntu has a PPA with this driver and Arch seems to have updated to it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I find your question hard to understand, but I believe your asking how to upgrade from:

kmod-nvidia-3.6.6-1.fc17.x86_64-304.60-1.fc17.2.x86_64

to

kmod-nvidia-3.6.7-4.fc17.x86_64-304.64-1.fc17.x86_64

FWIW, it's in the rpmfusion repo now, but I would advise against upgrading because of:

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=878811

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=879527

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=857614

In short, the nvidia driver causes X to crash and all the bugs being filed against fedora are being closed because they are nvidia bugs.

Comment: Sorry I realise now that my question is quite unclear. I'll update it

Comment: I updated my question. It looks like at some point, feodra automatically updated to 304.64, despite these bugs. So far I haven't experienced this problem.